# How do I make images change with a rock, paper, scissors game?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a Rock Paper Scissors game in JavaScript, but also have it where the computer outputs images to the HTML document. I've tried everything I know, and it won't work. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="Rock Paper Scissors.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Your choice:<img id="myImage" onafterprint="userImgDisplay()" src="blank.png" width="250px" height="250px"/>The computer's choice:<img id="myImage" onload="comImgDisplay()" src="blank.png" width="250px" height="250px"/>
      </p>`
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?","Don't use articles (i.e. the, a, etc.)").toLowerCase();

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

function userImgDisplay() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (userChoice = "rock") {
    image.src = "rock.png";
  }else if (userChoice = "paper") {
    image.src = "paper.png";
  }else if (userChoice = "scissors") {
    image.src = "scissors.png";
  }
}

function comImgDisplay() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (computerChoice = "rock") {
    image.src = "rock.png";
  }else if (computerChoice = "paper") {
    image.src = "paper.png";
  }else if (computerChoice = "scissors") {
    image.src = "scissors.png";
  }
}
```

The "rock.png", "paper.png", and "scissors.png" are based on their respective items, and "blank.png" is just a transparent image. This program will always display "rock.png" for my choice and nothing for the computer's. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser? `onafterprint` is not supported in Chrome, Safari or Opera

Comment: also, You need to change this (```if (userChoice = "rock")``` to ```if (userChoice == "rock")``` and do this for each one. This is how comparisons work in javascript. Currently, you are assigning the value with a single ```=``` sign

Comment: ^^^ looks like you are assigning rock to UserChoice... every time (instead of comparing UserChoise to rock)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Specifically, I'm using the Caret editor on the Acer Chromebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is not right, you are using `=` where it should be `==`

For example look at my changes to this method, you have issues like this in all your methods.

```
function comImgDisplay() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
 if (computerChoice == "rock") {
   image.src = "rock.png";
 }else if (computerChoice == "paper") {
  image.src = "paper.png";
 }else if (computerChoice =="scissors") {
  image.src = "scissors.png";
 }
}
```

For simplicity you could just do this:

```
function comImgDisplay() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   image.src = computerChoice  + ".png";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're making a game, I recommend using jQuery.

But if you want to do it like this, then here is the code. I fixed some syntax errors too.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?",
    "Don't use articles (i.e. the, a, etc.)").toLowerCase();
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) computerChoice = "rock";
else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) computerChoice = "paper";
else computerChoice = "scissors";
['userImgDisplay', 'comImgDisplay'].forEach(function(element) {
    window[element] = function() {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if (userChoice == "rock") image.setAttribute("src", "rock.png");
        else if (userChoice == "paper") image.setAttribute("src", "paper.png");
        else if (userChoice == "scissors") image.setAttribute("src", "scissors.png");
    }

});
```

Comment: Your refactoring of the two image display functions fails to take into account that one of the functions inspects `userChoice` and the other inspects `computerChoice`.